# Vue 3 - Options API - Using v-model and want to detect any changes which v-model shows

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm using v-model for with a Input field. What I want to achive is that when the v-model information (data) changes, I want to call an function like `change`:. @input and @change doesn't work. Any other idea's?

```
<template v-if="field.type == 'textLanguage'">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center">
    <!--begin::Label-->
    <div class="flex-grow-1">
      <label class="fs-6 fw-bold mb-2">{{ field.label }}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-solid" placeholder="" v-model="fieldData[field.field]" @change="update(field.field, fieldData[field.field])">
    </div>
    <!--end::Label-->
    <!--begin::Action-->
    <div class="btn btn-icon btn-active-light-primary position-relative w-30px h-30px w-md-40px h-md-40px" @click="doSomething()"><span class="svg-icon svg-icon-2x">
      <Icon name='Interface/Settings-02.svg'/>
      </span>
    </div>
    <!--end::Action-->
  </div>
</template>
```

I tried also Watch as function, which does nothing at all.

```
watch: {
 fieldData(test1, test2) {
   console.log(test1)
   console.log(test2)
 }
},
```

Comment: Use watch, docs https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: I tried. Doesn't work. Can't get any response. I updated my post with the watch function.

Comment: use `deep` param for your watcher. `watch: {deep:true, handler(){ }}`

Comment: Also you must have all the fields in the `fieldData` so that vue can mark them reactive. Otherwise adding fields dynamicly will not be watched. Check reactivity caveats section

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! How to get the key and value specific with watch? I want to know which key has been changed inside the JSON data.